# "this" within prototype is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have spent more than a hour on that.

What is wrong with this code?!

StudentController.js:

```
function StudentController() {
    this.studentService = {};
};

StudentController.prototype.findAll = function(req, res){
    this.studentService.something();
};

module.exports = StudentController;
```

app.js

```
var StudentController = require('./application/StudentController');
var studentController = new StudentController();
app.get('/students', studentController.findAll);
```

I am getting:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'something' of undefined

Why is "studentService" undefined ??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See specifically "Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers" in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't called in the right context.

Instead, try :

```
app.get('/students', studentController.findAll.bind(studentController));
```